# Showing the WordPress standard text area on a Woocommerce Single Product Page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, page-template, get-template-part

I'm trying to show the WordPress default text area on a Woocommerce Single Product Page but can't find the appropriate hook to add to the template? I would have thought it would've been well documented but I can't see anything online about it.

**Code**

Where's at the moment I'm using the `woocomerce_template_single_excerpt` I'm trying to find the full description (WordPress Editor) hook

```
<div class="col-8">
    <section class="section">
        <?php
        woocommerce_template_single_title();
        woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();
        woocommerce_template_single_price(); 
        woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
        ?>
    </section>
</div>
```

[image: WordPress Editor Area]

Comment: The default Wordpress Editor (textarea) is displayed on Woocommerce product single pages on "Description" TAB (and the short description (the other Text-area) is displayed under the main price… Here is a [visual guide for single product pages, with available hooks](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) …Or you can also see all that hooks [on the related templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks for the links but I went through those pages before but couldn't find the relevant hook for the full description (the WordPress Editor) only the short description

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I had a look into that, if I echo the content then it echo's the whole product again rather than just the content in the editor

Comment: The Full product description is located on the template: [`single-product/tabs/description.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php) and this template is loaded with the function [`woocommerce_default_product_tabs()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_theme_slug_for_templates.html#1718)… sorry but it uses the function `the_content();` which displays the full description. There is no other way. You can use the wordpress filter `the_content`, targeting  the single product with `is_product()`…

Comment: If you have a problem it comes from your theme customization *(and in this case you can contact your theme authors support pages).*